# Java: possible to stop scanner from pausing the console

Tags: java, loops, input

Trying to create a small program that can accept inputs through the console, whilst also outputting data through it. I use a loop for it, but whenever I try to add the ability to enter information into the console, it messes the program up.

In essence the code is like this

```
//outputting stuff to the console. All works fine

if(scanner.hasNext() && scanner.nextLine() != null){
   String input = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

That's contained in the loop that the bits for outputting the stuff also does. The problem is, the loop stops looping whenever I add in the bit about the scanner. So is there any way to stop the scanner halting the rest of the loop from outputting, or basically a way to make it so I don't have to hit enter for the loop to cycle again.

Edit: here's the whole segment of code, for better diagnosis. reader is an inputStream from another part of the code.

```
while (true){
            String input = self.reader.nextLine();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String[] subbed = input.split(" ");
            switch (subbed[0].toLowerCase()) {
                case "setid":
                    self.setPlayerID(Integer.parseInt(subbed[1]));
                    System.out.println("Player ID set to: " + self.playerID);
                    break;
                case "server":
                    System.out.println(input.replaceAll(subbed[0] + " ", ""));
                    break;

            }
            if(in.hasNext()){
                String out = in.nextLine();
            }

        }
```

Comment: can you add your Scanner declaration ?

Comment: `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)`

Comment: try this : if(scanner.hasNext()){
   String input = scanner.nextLine();
}

Comment: still hangs for input rather than continuing. Doesn't continue until it has at least 1 character is submitted. This has me well and truly stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't seem quite right here, what exactly is your 'self.reader' as the reader interfaces/inputStreams do not define nextLine().
Anyways, ignoring the first part of the code, Scanner is designed to block..so if you want it to NOT block you need to wrap it with a thread.  i.e.

```
class ScanThread extends Thread {
    private Scanner scanner;
    private volatile String scanLine;
    
    public ScanThread(Scanner scanner){
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    public String getLine(){
        return scanLine;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("CONSOLE NEXT LINE PLEASE:");
            scanLine = scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you create your scanner:

```
ScanThread threadedScanner = new ScanThread(new Scanner(System.in));
threadedScanner.start();
```

Thread to read from the scanner you do:

threadedScanner.getLine()

This will return the 'last line' the user entered on the console. (null if the user never hit Enter).  In this loop this will spam the output!, so not sure what your really looking for here, good luck.